# Can't read CSV file with Django 1,3,5 Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, django, csv

Models.py:

```
class Noads(models.Model):

nadnr = models.IntegerField()
nadbeschikbaar = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'nadnummers'

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%d" % (self.nadnr)
```

Funtion:

```
def csvimport(request):

sub = Noads()
file2 = ''
file = open('Map2.csv')

csv_file = csv.reader(file)

for row in csv_file:
    file2 += row

csv_file.close()

if request.method == "POST":
    #here i;m going to save the csv file into database
else:
    next = request.GET.get("next", "")

return render_to_response("user/nadinvoeren.html",
    {
        "next": next,
        "file2": file2,
    }, context_instance = RequestContext(request)
)
```

HTML:

```
<h1>NAD code invoeren{{ file2 }}</h1> // file2 is for checking the values within the csv file.

<h3 class="hthree">{{ nadcode1 }}Handmatig NAD codes invoeren</h3>

<form id="handnadcode" method="post" action="/accounts/nadinsert/">
    <div class="nadcodeinvoeren"><label for="nadcode1">NAD code #1</label><input type="text" tabindex="3" name="nadcode"></div>
    <div class="nadcodeinvoeren"><label for="nadcode2">NAD code #2</label><input type="text" tabindex="4" name="nadcode"></div>
    <div class="nadcodeinvoeren"><label for="nadcode3">NAD code #3</label><input type="text" tabindex="5" name="nadcode"></div>
    <input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Save Changes"> 
</form>
{% if err %}
    <p id="erro" style="color: red; float: left;clear: both; margin: 15px 0 7px 0;">You've inserted wrong or existing Nadcode</p>
{% endif %} 
<div class="nadcodeinvoeren" id="nadcodesfields"><input type="button" value="Meer invoervelden" name="nadcodesfields"></div>

<h3 class="hthree">NAD codes uploaden door middel van svg bestand</h3>

<form id="autnadcode" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/accounts/csv/">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload">Custom Upload</i> 
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" accept=".csv" hidden="true" name="csvupload"/>
    <p id="uploaded" style="float: left; clear: both; margin: 15px 0 7px 0;">File name: </p>
    <p id="err" class="erro" style="color: red; float: left;clear: both; margin: 15px 0 7px 0;">The file type is not csv</p>
    <input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Opslaan"> 
</form>
```

csv file:

```
id,nadnr,nadbeschikbaar
50,999,0
51,988,0
52,977,0
```

My question:

I almost tried everything to read the file/save/write. Am I doing something wrong? Can someone explain me so I can understand the problem and solve this error. **I'm quite new to Python and Django**.  It seems that I can't get any values back from the csv file, as you can see I'm returning a variable named file2 but it has no value. I want to return all values that are stored in the CSV file. I don't know how to debug, so it makes me harder to find the error on my own.

Version: `Django 1,3,5 Python 2.6.6`

Comment: You didn't say what the error is, or what is going wrong, or even what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't see the error-.- It seems that I can't get any values back from the csv file

Comment: "I can't get any values back [...]" What does this *concretely* mean? What *specifically* do you see (or fail to see) that tells you that you are not getting values back. Also, did you do some basic debugging? If yes, then what did you learn? Edit your question with this information.

Comment: I'm trying to get values from the csv file, If I can do this I can save it aswell into the database. Question edited @Louis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I couldn't read or get any values of the uploaded file was because I didn't use the temporary file. I've solved this by saving the file and deleting after it is inserted to the database